# Server-to-server communication with authorization in Cognito?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, amazon-cognito

I want to publish a REST API that will be used by external developers.

I was doing some research on how to do this with Cognito and I stumbled upon the `client_credentials` gran type, which seems to be the closest one, but it doesn't seem the way to go as it doesn't handles authorization, but just authentication.

How could I set a server-to-server communication with authorization in Cognito so that I could know in my API code which user is performing the HTTP request?